# Why does .NET's DayOfWeek enum doesn't have a null value?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Refering to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1008-enums-should-have-zero-value?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) every enum should have a null value, which totally makes sense. However I wanted to write a function that returns data based on the day of the week but as an optional parameter so you can get the data from all the week days if you don't provide a `DayOfWeek` value. Something like the following (demonstration code):

```
private List<Class> GetData(DayOfWeek Day = DayOfWeek.Empty)
{
}
```

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1) the `DayOfWeek` enum doesn't provide an empty value. Obviously i can work my way around by converting the DayOfWeek to a string or an integer, but basically it feels like this `DayOfWeek` enum speaks against Microsoft's own design guidelines?

Is there any reason why this enum is like it is or is this just a design flaw?

Comment: No enum in .NET  has any kind of null value. They may have a default 0 value.

Comment: The guideline says to have a 0 value. The enum has a 0 value (Sunday).

Comment: That articale says "should have a **zero** value". DayOfWeek _does_ have a zero value: Sunday. What it lacks is a "dont care" or "none" member.

Comment: Because the thing being modeled here (distinct weekdays) have no concept of "not a weekday"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Translation error - they mean `None`. (The original text of their link does say `null`).

Comment: Yes, I show it once I opened the link and switched to English

Comment: I should have checked the original english version, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text in English is clearer:

> A non-flags−attributed enumeration should define a member that has the
> value of zero so that the default value is a valid value of the
> enumeration.

*They key difference is that English is clearer that the requirement is for a value of zero (not `null`, since enum members can't have a `null` value).*

[`DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1) meets this requirement, because it has `Sunday`:

> Sunday    0   Indicates Sunday.

The *intent* here is that if you do code like https://dotnetfiddle.net/H4Eq1k (whereby you declare a variable of the enum type but don't assign anything to it, so it has the default 0 value) then you get meaningful results (i.e. 0 represents a valid value of the enum).

If what you are trying to do is allow some *optional* notion of `DayOfWeek` then you likely want a [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) parameter:

```
private List<Class> GetData(DayOfWeek? Day = null)
{
}
```

This will allow you to pass a day of the week if you want (with the value of `null` being used if you don't pass a value).

Comment: I totally forgot about nullables for a moment! That perfectly fits my need in this case. But just for clarification - although the `DayOfWeek` enum has a 0 value, compared to a usual enum design, `Sunday` is indeed a meaningful state of the enum where usually the value 0 should indicate an empty (or maybe a default) state. Sunday is neither an empty nor a default state.

Comment: The rule about an "Empty" or "None" member only applies when the natural values you would assign to the members do not otherwise have a natural `0` value. For `DayOfWeek`, `Sunday` is that member. If the first value were `1` and the last were `7`, then a `None` member would be required. Now compare that to NodaTime's [`IsoDayOfWeek`](https://nodatime.org/2.1.x/api/NodaTime.IsoDayOfWeek.html), where this is in fact how it is implemented because it uses ISO numbering for the days of the week: Monday through Sunday are 1 through 7. The docs explain that `None` is never actually returned.

Comment: The real rule is *"Always have a member with a value of 0 so that even an uninitialized instance will have the value of one of the members."*

Comment: `Sunday is neither an empty nor a default state.` It is a default state @EliasJohannes.